# My function is being called before the state is changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working in Reactjs and my database is Firebase.

I'm trying to retrieve data from my database and then checking data regarding it.

At the top, I have `const [group, setGroup] = useState(null);` for my group data. In my CheckGroupRelationship function, if checks the database using the group object data.

Initially I had the function called after the database call:

```
  const GetGroupInfo = async (uid) => {
    await props.firestore
      .collection("groups")
      .doc(uid)
      .get()
      .then(async (doc) => {
        if (!doc.exists) {
          console.log("No such document!");
        } else {
          setGroup({
            id: doc.data().id,
            ownerID: doc.data().ownerID,
            name: doc.data().name,
          });
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log("Error getting document", err);
      });
      CheckGroupRelationship();
  };
```

However, I would get the error "Group is null". So I moved the function called to the setState:

```
  const GetGroupInfo = async (id) => {
    await props.firestore
      .collection("groups")
      .doc(id)
      .get()
      .then(async (doc) => {
        if (!doc.exists) {
          console.log("No such document!");
        } else {
          setGroup(
            {
              id: doc.data().id,
              ownerID: doc.data().ownerID,
              name: doc.data().name,
              bio: doc.data().bio,
            },
            CheckGroupRelationship()
          );
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log("Error getting document", err);
      });
  };
```

This would still result in the "group is null" error. I'm not sure what else I can do to get the function to be called AFTER the state is set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the easy solution would be to use `useEffect`. In your case you can do this:

```js
const [group, setGroup] = useState(null);
useEffect(() => {
  if (group) {
    CheckGroupRelationship()
  }
}, [group])
```

What `useEffect` does here is waiting for `group` to change and when it changes it calls the inside callback. In this case you will have group updated there. Hope it helps, cheers

Comment: This worked for me though I had to make a couple changes. I added a "if (groupLoaded === false)" flag to prevent useEffect from constantly calling the database which I changed to true once CheckGroupRelationship finished